# Add custom then()-method to every function generated by promisifyAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, aerospike

I've recently started playing around with [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/) and their [Node driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aerospike). I think the database itself is phenomenal, but the client library has a minor hiccup:

```
// Read the same record from database 
client.get(key, function(err, rec, meta) {
  // Check for errors 
  if ( err.code == status.AEROSPIKE_OK ) {
    // The record was successfully read. 
    console.log(rec, meta);
  } else {
    // An error occurred 
    console.error('error:', err);
  }
});
```

Instead of returning `null` or `undefined` as the error when all went well, an object is always sent back. If `err.code === 0` all went well. This means that the library can not be wrapped with bluebird's `promisifyAll`.

I tried to fix this by adding yet another `then`-method after each function generated by `promisifyAll`.

```
getPromise().then((err, rec, meta) => {
  if(err.code === 0) {
    return {rec: rec, meta: meta};
  } else {
    return Promise.reject();
  }
}
```

I could not get it to work without explicitly doing it to every function manually. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You could alter the source for the driver, but that's impractical, so maybe you could just wrap it in a new function that returns null, and post an issue on Github for this.

Comment: @adeneo You're right. There is an issue similar to this, but it seems like it will not be altered since it is a breaking change, and lots of people are already using it.

Comment: @Tholle: Well you could always fork the project :-) Going against the nodejs conventions is hard to justify, it only causes problems (such as this).

Comment: @Bergi I agree :) I will bug the great guys over at Aerospike some more to maybe include a flag when the client is initialized to comply with the conventions.

Comment: @Tholle: They could just introduce a 2.0 version for the breaking change. Makes more sense than a flag imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like this is a case for Bluebird's [custom promisifier option](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var aerospike = Promise.promisifyAll(require('aerospike'), {
    promisifier: function(originalFunction, defaultPromisifer) {
        return defaultPromisifer(function() {
            var last = arguments.length-1;
            var callback = arguments[last];
            arguments[last] = function weirdAerospikeCallback(err, rec, meta) {
                if (!err || err.code == status.AEROSPIKE_OK)
                    callback(null, {rec: rec, meta: meta});
                else
                    callback(err);
            };
            originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks Bergi!

Comment: You might like to immunise yourself against some future fixed version of Aerospike by testing `if (!err || err.code == aerospike.status.AEROSPIKE_OK)`. Otherwise, one day you/someone may well try out an update and have trouble tracking the cause of a total apparant Aerospike failure.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Well I'd expect such a breaking change to be clearly described in the release notes of the update; so that you can remove this promisifier completely (maybe use `multiArgs: true`) deliberately. But I see your point, edited.